# How to connect CAN modules of two STM32 evalboards

Tags: can

I have two  stm32f407 discovery evalboards and I want to connect them using their CAN modules.

Is that possible without any CAN transceiver?

It comes to me logical but transceiver convert data differantially and it makes my mind confused.

Comment: Why would you not want a transceiver? If you don't need one because you don't need CAN reliable communication, use UART or SPI instead.

Comment: Cause im in quarantine and want to do maximum thing without hardware :)